# django redirects different links to same page

Tags: python, django, frontend

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'platoweb/index.html')

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'platoweb/about.html')
```

This is the views.py file.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index.html'),
    url(r'^$', views.about, name='about.html'),

]
```

This is the app urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^platoweb/index.html', include('platoweb.urls')),
    url(r'^platoweb/about.html', include('platoweb.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
# .   url(r'^posts/', include("posts.urls", namespace='posts')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

This is the global urls.py

Essentially, I'm trying to hit two different urls, index.html and about.html (and more later). However, when I run it, both index.html and about.html redirect to index.html.

I've tested both html files and they work just fine. Any ideas or thoughts?

Comment: your url pattern is same for index and about in your views.py

Comment: by url pattern you mean the url in my return statement right? One points to index and the other points to about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need change `global urls.py` like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^platoweb/', include('platoweb.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
# .   url(r'^posts/', include("posts.urls", namespace='posts')),
]
```

Then your `app urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^about$', views.about, name='about'),

]
```

Then url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/platoweb` will go to your index page, and `http://127.0.0.1:8000/platoweb/about` will goes to your about page.

Comment: Hey so I made the changes and ...8000/platoweb works but platoweb/about doesn't. I'm getting a 404 in the terminal. Any thoughts?

Comment: your template about.html is in your folder platoweb?

Comment: Yup, that's the path:

Desktop\platotots\platoweb\templates\platoweb

Comment: sorry, my bad, check the updated answer, I mention the file incorrectly